# Raspberry pi network

Tags: linux, network-programming, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is it possible to write a program that would connect and disconnect my raspberry pi, running raspbian, to my wifi network.  For instance I would like it to connect to my network when a picture is taken due to motion observed.  Then I would like it to connect itself to the network send out an email and then disconnect itself.  Is this possible and what is the simplest way to do this.

Note: When the raspberry pi is connected to the network the whole network seems to slow after a certain amount of time which is why I want it to connect and then disconnect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Pi is able to connect at will, then I assume it has an interface configured appropriately for your local network. Knowing this, connecting and disconnecting is as simple as the Bash command `ifup` and `ifdown`. If you're using a Bash script:

```
# some code for taking and saving a picture (I'll leave this to you) 

ifup wlan0
echo "Raspberry Pi just took a pic!" | mail -s "New picture taken" you@yourdomain.com
ifdown wlan0

# more code to finish out your program
```

Of course, replace `wlan0` with the relevant interface for your system (which may very well be wlan0). Happy coding! :)